# Hibernate: Schema-validation: missing table even after hibernate just generated the table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Whenever I try to connect to my database with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set to "validate" I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Logger] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1336)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1262)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at com.gamedacademy.gamedlogger.standalone.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:42)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [chatlogs]
```

this is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Logger" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Persistence provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Entity classes -->
        <class>com.gamedacademy.gamedlogger.data.ChatLogEntry</class>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chatlogs")
public class ChatLogEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "INT")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "server_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(32)")
    private String serverID;

    @Column(name = "sender_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID senderID;

    @Column(name = "message", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(256)")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "timestamp", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    /**
     * default constructor for JPA
     */
    public ChatLogEntry() {

    }

    public ChatLogEntry(String serverID, UUID senderID, String message, Timestamp time) {
        this.serverID = serverID;
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = time;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getServerID() {
        return serverID;
    }

    public UUID getSenderID() {
        return senderID;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am initializing everything:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gamedlogger";
        String dbUser = "gamedlogger";
        String dbPass = "Uu9wWBLe8sunZ4id";


        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbURL);
        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser);
        props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPass);



        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Logger", props);
        EntityManager loggerEntityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Ultimately my goal is to let Flyway manage my database migrations and use JPA/Hibernate for data access. But I am having trouble getting Hibernate to even load correctly. The database exists and is hosted locally using XAMPP (db is MariaDB 10.4.11 according to PHPMyAdmin) and the user/table definitely exists with full permissions as well. I have tried letting Hibernate generate the database from scratch (with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create) which it does without a problem, but when switch Hibernate back to validate and I am still getting the exact same error.

If I disable validation and just try running some code, hibernate does allow me to insert data into the table so I know it can access the database, I just can't seem to track down why hibernate's validation is refusing to recognize the table even after several hours on google and here on stackoverflow.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: nope, the project took a backburner with other priorities taking precendence so I haven't looked at it in a while but I believe where I got to was just disabling hibernate validation entirely and just kinda hoping it matched up correctly >_>